# Error al mostrar imágenes en correo phpmailer

Tags: imagen, phpmailer, email

Estoy enviando varios correos por phpmailer sin embargo en algunos correos no termina de mostrar las imágenes como por ejemplo en gmail o yahoo.

Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
/*=============================================
VERIFICACIÓN DE CORREO ELECTRÓNICO PHPMAILER    
=============================================*/ 


//$url = "https://www.url.com/";                        

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");

$url = Ruta::ctrRuta();

//echo "Por ahora la url es: ".$url;

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->isMail();

$mail->setFrom('newsletter@...com', 'título');          

$mail->addReplyTo('prueba@....com', 'Ttítulo');     

$mail->Subject = "¡Confirma tu direccion de email!";

$mail->addAddress($_POST["emailNewsletter"]);   

    //Prueba con ruta entera de la imagen.
$imagen1 = '<img src="https://www.url.com/views/images/imagen.jpg" alt="Ttitulo" class="img-newsletter">';                  

$mail->msgHTML('    

    <img src="'.$url.'views/images/imagen.jpg" alt="Titulo" class="img-newsletter">
    <p>Otra prueba de imagen con la ruta entera directa</p>
                        '.$imagen1.'

');

//Prueba de imagen adjunta.
$mail->AddAttachment("https://www.url.com/views/images/imagen.jpg");        

$envio = $mail->Send();

//Si no se envía phpmailer
if(!$envio){

    //Error en la verificación
    echo '<p class="alerta-confirmacion">!Error al verificar newsletter a tu dirección de correo electrónico!</p>';

    echo $_POST["regEmail"].$mail->ErrorInfo.'!';


}
//Confirmación de correo enviado al usuario
else{
    //Si se envía phpmailer y va todo bien                              

    echo '<p class="alerta-confirmacion">!No olvides verificar tu dirección de correo electrónico para confirmar tu registro!</p>';

}
```

Aquí solo he puesto la parte del código que afecta a esa zona como ejemplo, donde he probado con la variable `$url` que es igual a la ruta entera del servidor, también con `$imagen1` donde meto la ruta entera de img incluyendo la ruta entera de la image e incluso con una imagen de prueba adjunta y ninguna de las tres funciona.

¿Qué esto haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Quieres adjuntar una imagen al correo y luego incluirla referenciada en el mensaje HTML o quieres incluir en el HTML del correo una imagen externa para ser mostrada? Son dos cosas diferentes con sus ventajas/desventajas.

Comment: ¿Qué es `$url`?  Tienes que poner la ruta completa, incluyendo `http://www.` o `https://www.`

Comment: Hola OscarGarcia y A. Cedano.

Finalmente ese código estaba correcto, lo que daba problemas era que las imágenes de nuestro servidor no aparecían en los emails, si en el servidor pero no en los emails ya que probando otra cualquiera de la red con otra ruta carga perfectamente, así que en cuanto arreglemos esos permisos de imágenes en phpmailer con los del servidor asunto arreglado.

Gracias a ambos por vuestra ayuda.

PD: Sigo sin saber como dar puntuación positiva a usuarios que me ayudan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues la verdad vuelvo a responder a este tema ya que pensaba que iba  ser de un tema de "Hotlink Protection" y sin embargo a última hora probando esta opción sin poner https y poniendo la ruta de imágenes normal parece que funciona correctamente en los dos casos.

```
$mail->msgHTML('    

        <img src="views/images/imagen.jpg" alt="Titulo" class="img-newsletter">

     ');

    //Prueba de imagen adjunta.

    $mail->AddAttachment("views/images/imagen.jpg");
```

No sé si con https sigue teniendo ese problema por ese error que citas de evitar vínculos directos a otras páginas así que esa parte tendré que volver a revisarla bien y consultarla en el servidor. Pero como indico en el ejemplo así ya funciona correctamente.

Saludos.